# simple randon sampling simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation

How can i generate 100 samples of size 5 in a single command in r?

```
N <- 100
n=5
z<-c()
z=numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N){
  z[i]=sample(seq(1:N),size=n,replace=FALSE)
}
```

Where am wrong?

Comment: `replicate(100, sample(1:100, size=5))`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the sample to be taken from the numbers 1 to 100? If so, dsaxton's comment will give you this in a matrix. Or to get the samples in a list:

```
lapply(rep(1, 100), function(x) sample(x:100, size = 5))
```

Comment: thank you so much, you made my assignment. GOD bless you